# If something is found in the db table, php/mysql will update it

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the below to work correctly. I have the else working correctly, but I am running into problems in the if part. What it's doing is deleting the row and inserting 0 into the `hottest_cat` row. It should be inserting the value from `$dd`. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
public function change_category() {
        $dd = $this->input->post('dd');
        $sql = $this->db->get('default_hottest_cat');
        if ($sql->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $sql->row(); 
                $old = $row->hottest_cat;
                // Stuff is found in this table. Needs to be deleted first, then inserted.
                $this->db->delete('default_hottest_cat', array('hottest_cat' => $old));
                $this->db->insert('default_hottest_cat', array('hottest_cat' => $dd));
        } else {
            // Nothing is found in this table. Needs only to be inserted.
            $this->db->insert('default_hottest_cat', array('hottest_cat' => $dd));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the insert line commented out?

Comment: Because I was debugging it.

Comment: did you try to print the value of `dd`?

Answer (score 0):

Your is quite similiar to a problem I had answered.
Please check this for more info
[How to check if id already exists - codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125524/how-to-check-if-id-already-exists-codeigniter/16125882?noredirect=1#comment23034152_16125882)

The logic is

```
1.Select "the database table" with the value you had posted.(search)
2.Check the count of result_row(if found >0 , if not found =0)
3.If not found  'insert', if found 'update',( in your case delete)
```

Model

```
<?php
    class Cars_model extends CI_Model
    {   
        function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

         function check()
         {
            $query=null; //emptying in case 

            $dd= $_POST['dd'];    //getting from post value

            $query = $this->db->get_where('default_hottest_cat', array('dd' => $dd)); ၊၊၊။။//making selection
            $count= $query->num_rows();    //counting result from query

        if ($count === 0)  // data is not present
        {  
               $data = array(
                 'dd' => $dd
            );
           $this->db->insert('default_hottest_cat', $data); 
        }
           else //data is present
          {
               $this->db->delete('default_hottest_cat', array('dd'=>$dd));
           }
         }     
    }

?>
```